# Duvidas com PIVOT no Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

Boa tarde,

Estou com dificuldades para montar um Pivot no Oracle.

Minha query retornar as categorias no geral, então estou usando o pivot para contar a quantidade de categorias.

```
pivot(
count(CAT)
for CAT in (1 as cat1, 2 as cat2, 3 as cat3, 4 as cat4, 5 as cat5)
);
```

Até aqui beleza, meu problema é que tenho categorias acima de 5 e queria agrega-las num único alias.

Por exemplo:

6 e 7 as catX

8, 9 e 10 as catY

Mas não estou sabendo como coloco isso no pivot, alguém se habilita?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Poderia na consulta ter a concatenação, soma, etc... das categorias:

```
select ...,
       6||7 as catx, 
       8||9||10 as caty
  from
   ...
```

E no seu pivot fazer a referência.

```
pivot(
count(CAT)
for CAT in (1 as cat1, 2 as cat2, 3 as cat3, 4 as cat4, 5 as cat5, 6 as catx)
)
```

Answer (score -3):

@David vc matou a charada.

Só precisei colocar o || no pivot:

```
for CAT in (1 as cat1, 2 as cat2, 3 as cat3, 4 as cat4, 5 as cat5, 6||7 as catx, 8||9||10 as caty)
```

Deu certo!!!

Obg amigo =]